# How to reuse a css file in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, css, monorepo, turborepo

I am using Turborepo, and am wondering if there is a way that I can create a common css file and reuse it. For example, given the below architecture,

```
apps/
 |- client/
    |- index.tsx
packages/
 |- ui/
    |- global.css
    |- index.tsx
    |- ...
```

How can I do something like this?

**client/index.tsx:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import global.css from 'ui';

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
import "ui/global.css"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't seem to be working. I think I need to add some extra configuration in my package.json for the "ui" package to work?

Comment: Are you able to import anything from the `ui` package?

Comment: any one who solved this issue?